# Loopholes of proof that $f$ is strictly monotone on $I$ if $f$ is differentiable on the interval $I$, and $f'(x)\neq0$ for all $x\in I$

Tags: calculus

I have two proofs here-- are they rigorous enough? Or are there any loopholes in my proof? Thanks!

1. Suppose $f(x)$ is NOT strictly monotone, i.e. there are at least two zeroes for $f(x)-c$ for some constant $c$. Then by rolle's theorem, there must exist a number $d$ such that $f'(d)=0$ which contradicts the conditions.

Am I rigorous enough? For example, the prerequisite of Rolle's theorem is continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$, but the conditions imposed by the question only implies differentiability on $(a,b)$ (and thus, continuity on $(a,b)$ only)
Or, does the $c$ include the value $c=0$? do I need to separate it from the proof?
Or any other loopholes?

2. We claim that if $f'(x)\neq 0  \ \forall x \in I$, then $f'(x)>0$ or $f'(x)<0$ for all $x\in I$.
   suppose that $f'(x)<0$ for some $x_1$ and $f'(x)>0$ for some $x_2$, $x_1,x_2\in I$ . Then by Darboux's theorem, there must exist a $x_3 \in I$ such that $f'(x_3)=0$, which violates the conditions imposed by the question. Therefore $f'(x)>0$ or $f'(x)<0$ for all $x\in I$ and hence, strict monotonicity.

Should the claim "if $f'(x)\neq 0  \ \forall x \in I$, then $f'(x)>0$ or $f'(x)<0$ for all $x\in I^0$" be more correct? Do the endpoints matter?

Thanks!

Comment: $f$ is strictly monotonic on $[a',b']$ whenever $a<a'<b'<b$ so $f$ must be strictly monotonic on $(a,b)$.